# How to secure a Windows 2008 R2 server + SharePoint 2010 to be internet facing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, security

Need to use SharePoint 2010 as a public facing website. The standalone server will be plugged directly into DMZ.

What steps do I need to take to secure it for this type of environment?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely start with this:

1. http://www.winserverhelp.com/2010/05/hardening-windows-server-2008/
2. https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/ISO/Windows+2008R2+Server+Hardening+Checklist
3. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771361(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ISA Server or the new Threat Management Gateway for this?

Comment: Hmm no I haven't.  Is it a bit overkill for a standalone server?